# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined discord blacklistcommand

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

id is undefined

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "blacklist",
    description: `Blacklist a user from using commands`,
    checkArgs: true,
    arguments: "<user>",
    type: "discord",
    category: "admin",
    usesChat: false,
    sendEmbed: false,
    usesShield: false,
    adminPerms: true,
    execute(bot, database, arguments, options, embed, message) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("You can't use that.");

        const user = message.mentions.members.first();
        if (!user) {
            message.channel.send("**ERROR**: Please state a user to blacklist.");
            return;
        }
        const blacklistedrole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === "Blacklisted");
        if (message.mentions.members.first().roles.cache.has(blacklistedrole.id)) {
            message.channel.send(`**ERROR:** ${user} already has the \`Blacklist\` role.`);
            return;
        } else {
            user.roles.add(blacklistedrole.id);
            message.channel.send(`Gave ${user} the \`Blacklist\` role.`);
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: You get `id of undefined` from `blacklistedrole.id` because it could not find the role with name `Blacklisted` so `blacklistedrole` is undefined.

Comment: And please read  [ask] a question on SO. A bit more details would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

In the `execute` function, you are trying to find `blacklistedrole` However, you need to consider the possibility that blacklistedrole is not found in the code.

```
execute(bot, database, arguments, options, embed, message) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("You can't use that.");

    const user = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (!user) {
        message.channel.send("**ERROR**: Please state a user to blacklist.");
        return;
    }
    const blacklistedrole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === "Blacklisted");

    
    if(!blacklistedrole) { //If blacklistedrole no found, throw an error message
        message.channel.send("**ERROR**: ERROR MESSAGE HERE");
        return;
    }

    if (message.mentions.members.first().roles.cache.has(blacklistedrole.id)) {
        message.channel.send(`**ERROR:** ${user} already has the \`Blacklist\` role.`);
        return;
    } else {
        user.roles.add(blacklistedrole.id);
        message.channel.send(`Gave ${user} the \`Blacklist\` role.`);
    }
}
```